# Android Fragment Layout Issue (centre buttons vertically and horizontally)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I currently have this layout file which is used for a fragment inside tabs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

          <TableRow
              android:paddingTop="10dip"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip"
              android:paddingBottom="3dip"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn_Show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />
         </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:paddingTop="10dip"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip"
              android:paddingBottom="3dip"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />
        </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**The buttons are currently displaying in the centre vertically, but I also want they to display horizontally in the centre like the image shown below.**

[image]

I have tried using various ways of         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical | horizontal" but does not seem to work

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set width `TableRow` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` then make gravity `center` `android:layout_gravity="center"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

          <TableRow
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:paddingBottom="3dip"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip"
              android:paddingTop="10dip" >

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn_Show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:text="Button 2" />

         </TableRow>
          <TableRow
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:paddingBottom="3dip"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip"
              android:paddingTop="10dip" >
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />
        </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks thats great. Works great. Why do I need the FrameLayout surrounding the Linear layout? - thanks

Comment: for one button or one layout you can set multi gravity for example `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` if you want to make all child's in the center you have to group them with parent layout

Comment: I understand now, thank you.
So I need to keep the FrameLayout?

Comment: its up to you if you don't want to use anything else yes keep it , don't forget to set the answer ;)

Comment: Hi Jack,
I have posted another thread similar to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768090/android-fragment-layout-imageview-to-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, try and change your `LinearLayout` like this.-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

You also can remove the `FrameLayout`, your xml would look like this.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn_Show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

As a side note, you should consider keeping your dimensions values in a dimens resource file (i.e. `dimens.xml`)

Comment: Hi, yes this works great too. However If I remove the FrameLayout the buttons are no longer centred vertically.

Comment: Mmh weird, maybe not as straight forward as I told, look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you works great now with your new version.
Thank you for the tip about the dimes.xml, good advice.
Kind regards.