# How to center text on TextView's background

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have developing an application - listview with many items. In each item I have textview with background. How I can move my text to the center of textview    ?

My item code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lesson_name"
        android:id="@+id/tv_lesson"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Время"
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/teacher_name"
        android:id="@+id/tv_teacher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Кабинет"
        android:id="@+id/tv_cab"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        **android:id="@+id/tv_number"**
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1"
        android:textAlignment="inherit" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My textiew:

[image: my textview]

Any suggestions?

P.S I already tried android gravity = center, my textview moves to the center of the list item

Comment: You can check out this link i think so helpful you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757019/android-fragment-layout-issue-centre-buttons-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your `TextView`:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Should look something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Change your `Text View` as this.
>
> `android:layout_gravity` *property will move your full* `Text View`. And `android:gravity` *will only move your content which is inside that* `Text View` *that is the main difference between them*.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="2222"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is because of the default font padding,to remove the default padding you should add the following code in your layout xml inside TextView:
android:includeFontPadding="false" 
e.g.:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="2222"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />
```

Comment: Thanks, `android:includeFontPadding="false"` centered it correctly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'gravity' tag of the TextView to "center"

Answer (score 0):

Use folowing attribute:

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way,create one xml for background

test.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#f2f" />

                <size
                    android:height="150dp"
                    android:width="150dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]